# Estimating this integral

Tags: complex-analysis

My book says that $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \left|\frac{e^{a(R + it)}}{1 + e^{(R + it)}}\right| dt \leq Ce^{(a - 1)R},$$ where $0 < a < 1$ and $R$ is a real number. I don't see how this is true. Can somebody give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better bound would be the following

\begin{align}\left|\frac{e^{a(R + it)}}{1 + e^{(R + it)}}\right| &=\frac{|e^{aR} ||e^{iat}|}{|1+e^{R+it}|} \\&\leq \frac{e^{aR}}{|1-e^{R}|}\\
& = \frac{e^{(a-1)R}}{1-e^{-R}}
 \end{align}

Note that we used

$$|x+y| \geq ||x|-|y||$$